# Performance and readability - forEach vs reduce

Tags: javascript

I’ve finished a test on jsbin and I wonder what I could have done better.

Given data:

```
const orders = [
  { id: 1, quantity: 10, article: 'A' },
  { id: 2, quantity: 5, article: 'A' },
  { id: 3, quantity: 3, article: 'B' },
  { id: 4, quantity: 15, article: 'B' },
  { id: 5, quantity: 2, article: 'C' },
]

const prices = [
  { article: 'A', price: 5 },
  { article: 'B', price: 12 },
  { article: 'C', price: 9 },
]

const invoices = [
  { user: 'laurent@neoxam.com', order: 1 },
  { user: 'laurent@neoxam.com', order: 3 },
  { user: 'laurent@neoxam.com', order: 5 },
  { user: 'val@neoxam.com', order: 2 },
  { user: 'jood@neoxam.com', order: 4 },
]
```

My part:

```
const users = Object.values(invoices).reduce((acc,cur) => {

  const itemSelected = orders.find(e => e.id === cur.order);
  const items = prices.find(e => e.article === itemSelected.article);
  const userPanier = acc[cur.user] ? acc[cur.user].total : 0;

  return items ? { ...acc,
    [cur.user]: {
      user: cur.user,
      total: (items.price * itemSelected.quantity) + userPanier,
    }} : acc;
}, {});

console.clear()

const output = Object.values(users).map(e => e).sort((a,b) => b.total - a.total);
```

Expected:

```
const expected = [
  { user: 'jood@neoxam.com', total: 180 },
  { user: 'laurent@neoxam.com', total: 104 },
  { user: 'val@neoxam.com', total: 25 },
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(output) === JSON.stringify(expected))
```

First of all, naming is not ideal but I most focus on optimisation.

I dont like let and i prefere keep more immutability as possible, so I could have wrote:

```
const usersTotal = totalByUser(invoices);

const totalByUsers = (arr, acc={}) => {
     Object.values(invoices).forEach(e => {
          …
          acc[e.user] = userTotal 
     })
  return acc
}
```

The 2 is more elegant without one of my weard but loved returns-reduce-conditionnal-pattern

Any idea ?

I cant test better actualy because im on a phone. But I would be interested to read advices on it.

Comment: What exactly is your question? [ask]

Comment: In general, if something can be easily done with a forEach it tends to be way simpler to do it with the for each. Also: I doubt that there will be many differences performance-wise... In functional languages (e.g. Haskell) it can be important to use the most specific operation to do what you want, since the compiler may have rewrite rules that can automatically optimize the code, but those may not work using a generic `fold` (the equivalent of `reduce`). I don't think this is relevant for JS though.

Comment: I would create a function called `getTotalByUsers` and use `for..of` loop or `reduce` inside of it